# Python websockets, how to send message from function

Tags: python, websocket

I'm writing an update to my code to send a WebSocket message to a connected web browser that it needs to update its data (charting web app).
This message needs to be sent when the code has inserted new data into the MySQL database.  I will write some Javascript in the browser to go and get the update on receiving the message.

My test code:

```
import asyncio
#import time
import websockets


def readValues():
    '''do stuff that returns the values for database'''
    pass


def inserdata(val):
    '''insert values into mysql'''
    pass


async def ph(websocket, path):
    while True:
        message = 'update' 
        # here we receive message that the data
        # has been added and need to message the
        # browser to update
        print('socket executed')
        await websocket.send(message)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        # shouldn't be needed as message
        # sent only when updated data
        # inserted(every 20s)


async def main():  # maybe use this to get/write to the database etc
    while True:  # instead of the loop at bottom
        print('main executed')
        await asyncio.sleep(20)

start_server = websockets.serve(ph, '0.0.0.0', 5678)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

#below copied from current program
'''
while 1:
    try:
        a = readValues() #read valves from a function
        insertdata(a) #function to write values to mysql

        #some method to send the message to the web browser via -
        #websocket, that it needs to get the new data

        time.sleep(20) #wait and then do it again
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
'''
```

I can send a message using the message variable.

I need the readValues and insert data functions to run continuously every 20sec regardless of what's happening with the WebSocket.

But I can't work out how to send a message to the browser from the function that updates the database.  And I can't work out the best method to run the WebSocket process and the updating of the database at the same time.

I've written comments in the code to try and help you understand what I'm trying to do.

Hope you can understand, thanks, Guys.

Update: Thanks Nathan:
I changed the code and do 2 files like the below:
Server:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def ph(websocket, path):
    while True:
        need_update = await websocket.recv()
        print('socket executed')
        await websocket.send(need_update)


start_server = websockets.serve(ph, '0.0.0.0', 5678)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

process file:

```
import asyncio
import time
import websockets

async def main():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:5678') as websocket:
        while 1:
            try:
                #a = readValues() #read values from a function
                #insertdata(a) #function to write values to mysql
                await websocket.send("updated")
                print('data updated')
                time.sleep(20) #wait and then do it again
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

I then ran both of these (eaxctly as shown) and opened a web browser
with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>
        Test
        </h3>
        <p>
            <div id="log"></div>
        </p>
        <script>
            // helper function: log message to screen
            function log(msg) {
                document.getElementById('log').innerText += msg + '\n';
            }

            // setup websocket with callbacks
            var ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.224:5678/');
            ws.onopen = function() {
                log('CONNECT');
            };
            ws.onclose = function() {
                log('DISCONNECT');
            };
            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                log('MESSAGE: ' + event.data);
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything seems fine until I open the browser as above.
Then nothing comes to the browser and apart from the 'connect' result.

WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason

appears on both scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a socket connexion between the "database handler" and the socket server :

create a second script with the main loop:

```
 async def main():
    async with websockets.connect(websocket_address) as websocket:
        while 1:
            try:
                a = readValues() #read values from a function
                insertdata(a) #function to write values to mysql
                await websocket.send("some token to recognize that it's the db socket")
                time.sleep(20) #wait and then do it again
             except Exception as e:
                print(e)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

then on the other script you could have :

```
    USERS = set()
    def register(websocket):
        USERS.add(websocket)

    async def ph(websocket, path):
        while True:
            register(websocket) #not sure if you need to place it here
            need_update = await websocket.recv()
            #check unique token to verify that it's the database
            message = 'update'#here we receive message that the data
                              #has been added and need to message the
                              #browser to update
            print('socket executed')
            if USERS:       # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
                await asyncio.wait([user.send(message) for user in USERS])


    start_server = websockets.serve(ph, '0.0.0.0', 5678)

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, made some progress, but still not quite there, see my update.

Comment: Since the 2 scripts are on the same machine, maybe I should use some other method to communicate to the websocket server script to send update message.

Comment: Looked a bit harder at it, think maybe the server is not broadcasting to all clients.  But not sure how to set that up.

Comment: to broadcast the message to all the clients you need to setup the websocket like so in the script : https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#synchronization-example

Comment: indeed you need to broadcast to all clients, you're having a SIGV because the script doesn't know to whom he has to send the message, I'll edit my answer

Comment: The fact that it is on the same machine doesn't change anything, the other way you could communicate between the 2 scripts would be UNIX Sockets (if you're on a UNIX based computer) or the Windows equivalent; but it's almost the same thing

Comment: Yeah, I've modded the example on the websockets document site, the syncro example, in conjunction with your example and the example at the top.  Think I have it working, will know when I've integrated it all in.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Chris Please can you post complete solution. gist or somewhere else. Thank you !

Comment: @hannes-ach, The webserver for my graphs is also an MQTT server.  It looks like I changed the code (it was awhile ago this) so that the client web browser subscribed to a topic called 'newdata'.  When the python code sent new data to mysql, it then sent '1' to the MQTT topic.  This then signals to the browser to get new data and add it to the graph dynamically.  Not sure why I changed it to this, but I must have thought it was easier at the time.  If you'd like more info... then message me directly.